# When people quote salary figures in Europe*, do they mean after or before income tax?

Tags: united-kingdom, taxes, eu, salary

Do people mean after or before income tax when they quote salary figures in Europe?

For example, do salary quotes in [glassdoor](https://www.glassdoor.com/Salaries/london-software-engineer-salary-SRCH_IL.0,6_IM1035_KO7,24.htm) or other salary sites are take-home salaries?

I was wondering this because they do quote product prices after "sales" tax.

Comment: In the countries I am familiar with, it's usually before taxes and it says so explicitly (words like “brut” or “Brutto”).

Comment: An employer does not know your take-home pay, because the amount of taxes paid depends on personal circumstances.  VAT does not depend on personal circumstances and is the same for everybody.

Comment: @gerrit I don't think you can generalise that to all of Europe. In Belgium, as far as I know, employers transfer wages after most taxes have been deducted; the income taxes go directly from the employer to the state.

Comment: @ThomasAnderson: that sales tax point is debatable, it's a tax that the shop pays after the sale. Arguably the higher price is before sales tax was paid.

Comment: @ChristopheStrobbe: but presumably the amount they send is just an initial estimate, that can be corrected when you file your tax statement for the year and e.g. show you can deduct from your income?

Comment: @Gala for the sake of those who don't know, I will mention that *brut* and *brutto* correspond to the English *gross,* as in *gross pay.*   This is opposed, of course, to *net pay,* although those who say *brutto* will generally say *netto.*

Comment: @ChristopheStrobbe Employers know how much they withhold for taxes for each employee, but as Aganju's answer notes, when they are advertising a position, they have no idea who will be filling it, and no idea about the factors that will affect the eventual employee's withholding.  In particular, taxes generally depend on family size and household income.

Answer (score 8):

As the same gross salary can and will result in very different net payments to the employee, it does not make much sense to discuss salaries in 'net'. In any job description or offer, and in most discussions, salaries mentioned are therefore *gross* values.

It depends of course of the circumstances - a job that somebody currently *has* results in a well defined net payment to *him*, and he might tell his friends *his* net payments. However, as anyone else in the same position for the same company would probably get a different net payment, the information is not very useful, and a gross salary would actually give more information.

You will never get a job offer or description with a *net* payment, it does not make sense.